# Using an async call of my database

Tags: android, sqlite, asynchronous, adapter

I am trying to make a list-view for my android app with a footer button at the end.
I am trying to read the elements from my db,putting them in a list using the limit sql command end each time I press the footer button then I want to load the next elements from my db etc.

The code works fine until I press the button for my async call and then I get an exception.

This is my class:

```
public class UIHistoryListActivity extends ListActivity {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    EfficientAdapter adap;
    Databasehandler db = new Databasehandler(this);
    List<Message> messages;
    ArrayList<Message> menuItems = new ArrayList<Message>();
    int current_page = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int limit = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss",
                new java.util.Date());

        db.addMessage(new Message("6983583727", "Hi Lakis", 1,
                (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date())));

        db.addMessage(new Message("1234567789", "Hi Takis", 1,
                (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date())));

        db.addMessage(new Message("1234344789", "Hi Makis", 1,
                (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date())));

        db.addMessage(new Message("1234553229", "Hi Sakis", 0,
                (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date())));

        db.addMessage(new Message("1234567781", "Hi Akis", 1,
                (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date())));
        db.addMessage(new Message("6983583727", "Hi Qakis", 1,
                (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date())));

        db.addMessage(new Message("1234567789", "Hi Wakis", 1,
                (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date())));

        db.addMessage(new Message("1234344789", "Hi Eakis", 1,
                (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date())));

        db.addMessage(new Message("1234553229", "Hi Yakis", 0,
                (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date())));

        db.addMessage(new Message("1234567781", "Hi Ukis", 1,
                (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date())));

                //putting the first 5 messages of my db on the list
        messages = db.getMessages(0, 5);
        index += 5;
        limit = limit + 5;
        for (Message mg : messages) {
            menuItems.add(new Message(mg.getID(), mg.getPhoneNumber(), mg
                    .getBody(), mg.getStatus(), mg.getDate()));

        }
        /*
         * menuItems.add(new Message(1, "1234553229", "Hi Sakis", 0, "lala"));
         * menuItems.add(new Message(1, "1234553229", "Hi Lakis", 0, "lala"));
         * menuItems.add(new Message(1, "1234553229", "Hi Takis", 0, "lala"));
         * menuItems.add(new Message(1, "1234553229", "Hi Aakis", 0, "lala"));
         * menuItems.add(new Message(1, "1234553229", "Hi Qakis", 1, "lala"));
         * menuItems.add(new Message(1, "1234553229", "Hi Wakis", 1, "lala"));
         * menuItems.add(new Message(1, "1234553229", "Hi Eakis", 0, "lala"));
         * menuItems.add(new Message(1, "1234553229", "Hi Rakis", 0, "lala"));
         * menuItems.add(new Message(1, "1234553229", "Hi Yakis", 1, "lala"));
         * menuItems.add(new Message(1, "1234553229", "Hi Uakis", 0, "lala"));
         * menuItems.add(new Message(1, "1234553229", "Hi Oakis", 0, "lala"));
         */
        adap = new EfficientAdapter(this, menuItems);

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Creating a button - Load More
        Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
        btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");

        btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Starting a new async task
                // CharSequence text = "Ok dude you pressed me ";

                // Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                // toast.show();
                new loadMoreListView().execute();
            }
        });
        // Adding button to listview at footer
        lv.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);

        setListAdapter(adap);
        // adap = new ListViewAdapter(this, messages);
        lv.setAdapter(adap);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click-" + String.valueOf(position),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * Async Task that send a request to url Gets new list view data Appends to
     * list view
     * */
    private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<List<Message>, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UIHistoryListActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(List<Message>... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // UIHistoryListActivity.this
            // ListView lv = getListView();
            // for (Message mg : messages) {
            // menuItems.add(new Message(mg.getID(), mg.getPhoneNumber(), mg
            // .getBody(), mg.getStatus(), mg.getDate()));
            //
            // }

            // setListAdapter(adap);
            // adap = new ListViewAdapter(this, messages);
            // lv.setAdapter(adap);
            current_page = current_page + 1;

                        //putting the next 5 messages of my db on the list
            messages = db.getMessages(index, limit);
                        index += limit;
            limit = index + 5;


            ListView lv = getListView();
            for (Message mg : messages) {
                menuItems.add(new Message(mg.getID(), mg.getPhoneNumber(), mg
                        .getBody(), mg.getStatus(), mg.getDate()));
            }
            //setListAdapter(adap); edw petouse exception
            // adap = new ListViewAdapter(this, messages);
            adap = new EfficientAdapter(UIHistoryListActivity.this, menuItems);
            lv.setAdapter(adap);

            // Setting new scroll position
            int currentPosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            lv.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // closing progress dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    public static class EfficientAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message>
            implements Filterable {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        // private Bitmap mIcon1;
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<Message> values;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> values) {
            // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
            super(context, R.layout.mycontent, values);
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        /**
         * Make a view to hold each row.
         * 
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView1(int, android.view.View,
         *      android.view.ViewGroup)
         */
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid
            // unneccessary calls
            // to findViewById() on each row.
            ViewHolder holder;
            // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is
            // no need
            // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView
            // supplied
            // by ListView is null.

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mycontent, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.body = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.body);
                holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
                holder.from = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.from);
                holder.status = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.status);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }

            else {
                // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
                // and the ImageView.
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                private int pos = position;

                // private String toId =
                // Integer.toString(values.get(position).getId());
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Click-" + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });
            // holder.textLine.setText(TitleString[position] +
            // String.valueOf(position));

            holder.body.setText(getItem(position).getBody());
            holder.date.setText(getItem(position).getDate());
            holder.from.setText(getItem(position).getPhoneNumber());
            holder.status
                    .setText(String.valueOf(getItem(position).getStatus()));
            return convertView;

        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView from;
            TextView date;
            TextView body;
            TextView status;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return values.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Message getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return values.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        db.close();
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: OK i edited my logcat on my question

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ListView in doInBackground because it is different thread (not UI thread). Everything you want to do in UI thread (such as setting adapter to listview) must be done in onPostExecute.
Please read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) about AsyncTasks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved
I should make a new runnable each time i call the async

```
private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UIHistoryListActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                List<Message> messages;

                current_page = current_page + 1;
                messages = db.getMessages(index, limit);
                index += limit;
                limit = index + 5;
                ListView lv = getListView();
                for (Message mg : messages) {
                    menuItems.add(new Message(mg.getID(), mg
                            .getPhoneNumber(), mg.getBody(),
                            mg.getStatus(), mg.getDate()));
                }
                // Setting new scroll position
                int currentPosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                adap = new EfficientAdapter(UIHistoryListActivity.this,
                        menuItems);
                lv.setAdapter(adap);

                lv.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // closing progress dialog
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: NO! You don't understand AsyncTask and you are using it in wrong way. There is no point in using async task if you are doing runInUIThread inside doInBackground.